# Regex ignores negative lookahead

Tags: regex, pyspark

I've got the following string:

`#index 1#n John Doe#a some University#pc 7#cn 4#hi 1#pi 0.5889`

And want to extract the part between `#n` and the following `#` with regex. The result should then be:

`"John Doe"`

This works with the following regex:

`(?<=#cn\s).(?:(?!#).)*`

However, if the string looks as follows:

`#index 1#n #a some University#pc 7#cn 4#hi 1#pi 0.5889`

The regex returns:

`"#a some University"`

But I need it to return an empty string. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do that by extracting one or more chars other than `#` after `#n` and a whitespace:

```py
(?<=#n\s)[^#]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3J6Isn/2). The `(?<=#n\s)` positive lookbehind matches a location immediately preceded with `#n` and a whitespace, and `[^#]+` matches one or more chars other than `#`.

If there can be any one or more whitespaces, you can use a capturing group. In PySpark, it will look like

```py
df.withColumn("result", regexp_extract(col("source"), r"#n\s+([^#]+)", 1))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3J6Isn/3). With `#n\s+([^#]+)`, you match `#n`, one or more whitespaces, and then capture one or more non-`#`s into Group 1.